# listing .cpp or .o in makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I see in my current code base 2 patterns in makefiles:

1. list all cpp files
2. list all cpp files, but with the extension changed into `.o`

Example:

ex1.mk

```
...
SRCS=src1.cpp src2.cpp ...
...
```

ex2.mk

```
...
OBJS=src1.o src2.o ...
...
```

From my novice understanding on makefiles the 2 approaches seem to be interchangeable and any of them sufficient. Looking on tutorials about makefiles I can see both of them in the same file, sometimes like:

```
OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
```

What is the difference between `SRCS` and `OBJS`? Do I need to define both `SRCS` and `OBJS`? If yes, why does it work by defining only `SRCS` or `OBJS`? If no, how do I choose between defining `SRCS` and `OBJS`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define `SRCS`, then the `OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)` rule defines `OBJS` from it by replacing the suffixes.

If you define `OBJS`, then Make knows that a `.o` file may be created by compiling a `.cpp` file.

Either way is OK.  It'd be nice to consolidate and use one style in a given project.

Comment: I know, `OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)` rule defines `OBJS` from `SRCS` by replacing the suffixes., but my questions is: why would anyone add both `SRCS` and `OBJS` if any of them is enough?

Comment: @Felics: Well you wouldn't explicitly list everything twice I hope.  One of them is used to implicitly define the other.  It doesn't matter which direction you go: SRCS->OBJS or OBJS->SRCS.

Comment: How does OBJS->SRCS works? For example if I have in the same folder src1.cpp and src1.cc and src1.c and I list OBJS=src1.o which of the files is compiled? Are the conversions rules for SRCS->OBJS and OBJS->SRCS listed anywhere?

Comment: @Felics: If you have `src1.cpp` and `src1.cc` and `src1.c` in the same folder you are Doing It Wrong and simply need to stop doing that.  The rule for SRCS->OBJS is listed right in your question and in my answer.  For the other direction, it's built in to Make.

Comment: I know the rules are built into Make, otherwise it won't work. Are they documented anywhere? I hope there is another way of finding the rules than reading Make source code.

Comment: For GNU Make the catalog of implicit rules is here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules